# Flutter: Is it possible to save image to gallery without using requestLegacyExternalStorage or MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission?

Tags: android, flutter, android-permissions, android-11

Google started sending the following message to developers, that means we won't be able to use requestLegacyExternalStorage flag soon, because targeting Android 11 will be soon a requirement and even the alternative permission MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE will require good reason to get approval. Not sure if saving image to Gallery is good enough reason for Google to allow it.

Is that absolutely necessary to request this permission to save an image to gallery, or we can get rid of it? In seems that the most popular packages **gallery_saver** and **image_gallery_saver** both require it.

**Message from Google:**

> We've detected that your app contains the requestLegacyExternalStorage flag in the manifest file of 1 or more of
> your app bundles or APKs. Developers with apps on devices running
> Android 11+ must use Scoped Storage to give users better access
> control over their device storage. To release your app on Android 11
> or newer after May 5th, you must either:
>
> - Update your app to use more
>   privacy friendly best practices, such as the Storage Access Framework
>   or Media Store API
> - Update your app to declare the All files access
>   (MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) permission in the manifest file, and
>   complete the All files access permission declaration in Play Console
>   from May 5th
> - Remove the All files access permission from your app
>   entirely For apps targeting Android 11, the
>   requestLegacyExternalStorage flag will be ignored.
>
> You must use the All files access permission to retain broad access. Apps requesting access to the All files access permission without a permitted use will
> be removed from Google Play, and you won't be able to publish updates.

Comment: Saving to the gallery? What do you mean? There are Gallery apps and your device has storage. One can save to storage but not to apps.

Comment: @blackapps This is the term widely used - save photo to gallery - so that people can find the photo in the gallery app after that - both packages I mentioned above gallery_saver and image_gallery_saver do just that - that doesn’t mean they save to the gallery app literally.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, `gallery_saver: ^latest-version` handles it (it's only for images and videos)
It uses scoped storage for Android 11 and above.

https://pub.dev/packages/gallery_saver

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).